# Адаптивный дизайн

Tags: css

Рисую адаптивный дизайн (пытаюсь)
Сколько вариаций дизайна нужно сделать?) Точнее сколько значений min-width существует?)
    [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) only screen and (min-width: ???)

Comment: Народ, вы гдееее???((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь есть список стандартных разрешений, которые стоит учитывать:

- [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Также как вариант можно посмотреть на CSS фреймворки для сохдание адаптивного дизайна. Например [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/).